# How to close the dialog of android open by the select tag of html

Tags: android, jquery, html

I am creating a web application for the android and Iphone. Now my html page a select tag and when i select it on android browser it opens the default spinner dialog of android with Previous Next and Done button.

```
 <select  id="select-choice-presence" data-role="none"  

                 onChange="onUserStatusChange(this.value)"
                 style="width:150px;border:2px solid #333;"> 
            <option value="Online">Online</option>                                
            <option value="Away">Away</option>
            <option value="BeRightBack">Be Right Back</option>
            <option value="Busy">Busy</option>
            <option value="OutToLunch">Out To lunch</option>
            <option value="InAMeeting">In A Meeting</option>
            <option value="Offline">Appear Offline</option>
            <option value="Logout">Logout</option>
        </select>
```

[image]

I am capturing onChange event to get the event when the value of the select tag is changes but it is not closing the spinner dialog . So i want to capture the event when either the user closes the dialog by pressing done button or when user select any option dialog will close it self.

looking for help

Answer (score 0):

```
$('#menu_options').change(function() 
                    {
                        var id = $(this).children(":selected").attr("id");
                         console.log(id);
                        console.log($(this)[0].selectedIndex);
                        desck = descriptions[$(this)[0].selectedIndex];
                        console.log(desck);
                        loadMenuDetail($(this).val(),subTempId,id,desck);
                    });
```

Above code is for jQuery Mobile. This is working fine in my android webview. 
"menu_options" is id of your select tag in HTML

Comment: The same thing i am doing in onUserStatusChange(this.value) function. But the problem is that it will call when the user changes the option. But a Done button is above the dialog. I have attached the screenshot for your reference

Comment: This is not the default Spinner Dialog I guess.

Comment: Unfortunately not only on the Galaxy S2 phone. I've found that dialog on every Samsung Android device I've tested.

Answer (score 0):

```
$('select').change(function() {
    // DO SOMETHING

    // close the android select dialog
    $(this).blur();
});
```